# Activation of network connection failed. Kali linux v2.0

Tags: gnome3, kali-linux, networkmanager, firmware, dsl

I can't connect to internet via wired, adding DSL profile with user and password.

[image]

While installing kali linux 2.0 there was a warning telling that there is missing non-free firmware

```
`rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw`
```

but it is in /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/

[image]

Have Realtek RTL8139/810x Fast Ethernet Adapter PCI.

Was no problem on previous versions of Kali.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem but have found no resolution.
sometimes I can fix it by:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan1 down
```

wait a little and try:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
ifconfig wlan1 up
```

Comment: use ip which is a native linux command to do the same: **ip link set wlan0 up**